# Remove special characters in a text file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, special-characters, sql

I have a text file which contains in each line a sql query.

For each line, I need to remove some special characters.

Expl: if I have:

```
select * from Users;
insert into Users values ('UR01','Kim','Director');
```

the result file must be match:

```
select * from Users
insert into Users values UR01 Kim Director
```

Comment: FWIW, all the solutions here will add a trailing space on each line ending in one of those chars (one can't see the space in terminal but it's there...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/[;,()'\'']/ /g;s/  */ /g' input.sql > output.txt
```

or, if you rather want to specify what characters to keep:

```
sed -e 's/[^a-zA-Z*0-9]/ /g;s/  */ /g' input.sql > output.txt
```

Comment: this delete * ...

Comment: @choroba this command delete some characters but not all

Comment: @AomineDaiki: Check the update.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tr`:

```
$ tr -s "()',;" " " < data
select * from Users 
insert into Users values UR01 Kim Director
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/[;(),'\'']/," "); gsub(/  */," "); print}' your_file
```

Comment: -1 When I run this in a terminal, nothing happens. Please expand your answer so that it can be used without much prior knowledge.

Comment: you need to provide file at last, i edited it, check the update

Comment: @A.B i tried it in a terminal and it's ok

Comment: ok, it works now.